# ORDER BY rand() and group with group_id

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I want to select rows in random order by sorted by `group_id`:

```
id  group_id
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   4
```

I Would like to them to be sorted like below or randomized but still grouped:

```
id  group_id
5   3
3   2
4   2
1   1
2   1
6   4
```

Below will sort them but i would like the sort to be random. How to achieve this?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY group_id DESC
```

Below is an example query I am figuring out for the actual application.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT requests.*, accounts.username, accounts.password
FROM requests LEFT JOIN accounts ON requests.acc_id = accounts.id
WHERE requests.status NOT IN(1) AND accounts.status=1 ORDER BY RAND()
)  AS subquery GROUP BY acc_id
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure it out, but you basically want to sort _randomly_ on `group_id` right? In other words, you want a random order, where all rows with the same `group_id` are next to each other?

Comment: You should not use `ORDER BY RAND()` as it not only tells mysql "please throw away all of the indexes" but also "write out the entire result set to a disk and use filesort". Your table might be small enough right now that this is not noticeable, but this will become *exponentially worse* as the dataset grows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try ordering by a random number with a seed dependent on the `group_id`, yet with a random factor.
Like this:

```
SET @seed = 100*RAND();
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND(group_id*@seed);
```

Comment: this works great! may you please explain your logic behind this! thanks

Comment: Giving the `RAND()` function an argument ties the outcome to the input - e.g. the value sequence from RAND is always the same for the equal initializers. Plus - (from the MySQL `RAND()` docs) "If a nonconstant initializer (such as a column name) is used as the argument, the seed is initialized with the value for each invocation of `RAND()`.". So, `RAND(group_id)` gives a constant pseudorandom number based on `group_id` which we can order on and get the expected result. The random seed to the initializer only ensures the result is different on every query execution.

Comment: How does re-initializing the pseudo random generator for every row have any advantage over just `ORDER BY RAND()` ? With the pattern in this answer, the order of the rows is essentially "fixed" by the initial setting of  @seed.

Comment: `RAND()` would return different value on every invocation while result of `RAND(N)` where N is a column not a constant, is "random" but equal for equal values of N which means it acts as a random tag to every `group_id`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery that randomly orders all the group IDs and assigns a position to them with a user variable. Then join that with the original table and order it by the position.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group_id
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT group_id, @position := @position + 1 as position
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(group_id) AS group_id
            FROM yourTable
            ORDER BY RAND()) AS x
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @position := 0) AS var) AS t2
ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id
ORDER BY position, id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc839/8)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding why the other answers are as involved as they are.

If you need the rows in a random order, just do  `ORDER BY RAND()`.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.group_id
  FROM `table` t
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

---

Note that RAND() isn't truly random, it's a *pseudo*-random generator.

---

I'm not understanding why you need an inline view. You can perform the GROUP BY operation without an inline view. Given the GROUP BY, there's no need to do an unnecessary ORDER BY operation in the inline view.

```
 SELECT requests.*
      , accounts.username
      , accounts.password
   FROM requests
   LEFT
   JOIN accounts
     ON requests.acc_id = accounts.id
  WHERE requests.status NOT IN(1)
    AND accounts.status=1
  GROUP
     BY acc_id
  ORDER
     BY RAND()
```